# Does trading Pokemon that evolves on trade give both Pokedex entries?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation, pokemon-series

I'm in the process of filling in my Pokedex in Black 2/White 2 so this question is mostly concerned with the fifth generation. I was wondering if I could trade over a Pokemon (say Haunter) and get an entry in my Pokedex for Haunter and Gengar?

Comment: In Pokémon Red you'd get both entries, but I can't verify if it still does so in the newer generations. I think it should still be true. Your trading partner won't get the Gengar entry, though, unless you trade it back.

Comment: I would just trade for the final version and use it to breed the lower evolutions. Saves you one evolution item if it is needed. I have been doing this for 3 gens (Pt->HG->White) for many such pokes' with trade + item evolutions.

Comment: @SamyamA That's a good idea for the ones that require items to evolve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *sending* partner receives no entry for the *evolved* Pokémon, while the *receiving* partner receives both entries.

There is no feedback to the sender that the Pokémon evolved, and for the receiver it simply evolves on arrival.